# Open a fragment from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

I have the following issue. I have an activity with 4 fragments. One of them contains a list of names, when I click on a name another activity is started using intent ecc. This activity displays the personal informations related to the name and contains a button. The button removes the name from the list using the DELETE request via Http (also personal informations are retrieved using Http, POST).

This all works fine, but I would like to know how can I return to the fragment that shows the list of names from this very last activity to view again the list with the names minus the selected one. Suggestions or links where I can get some info are very welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

To go back to your previous Fragment use:

```
getActivity().getFragmentsManager().popBackStack()
```

The back stack allows the user to reverse a fragment transaction (navigate backwards). Using popBackStack will simulate the back behaviour of the back button. Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html an use the one most suited to your needs.

Comment: it says that getActivity() is undefined, what can I use instead of it?

Comment: I solved the problem of getActivity using this instruction:           Activity activity = ThisActivity.this;
              activity.getFragmentManager().popBackStack();  but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Probably there is no point in calling getActivity. When your fragments are extended from FragmentActivity class use this.getFragmentsManager instead of getActivity().getFragmentsManager()....

Comment: @Camilla you will need to check the documentation provide in the link to find the suited popBackStack methode. My gues is you need popBackStackImmediate() . Otherwise you need to check the backstack if the previous fragment is in the backstack and try to pop it using it's identification or text tag.

Comment: ok, thank you, I'll give a look to the documentation right now.

Comment: I read that getFragmentsManager calls the fragments associated with the activity. In my case this doesn't work since the activity is started by the fragment which is supported by another activity...

Comment: Ok, I suppose i understand your problem...in that case you could do the following super.onBackPressed() (this is kindof messy) better do open the new activity with startActivityForResult() and then to go back to the previous activity do finishActivity(). Third option is keeping track of your activity stack by using flags http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html .

Comment: super.onBackPressed()  works but it doesn't save my changes, I'll give a look to the flags. P.s. thank you, your are very helpful!

Comment: you should save your changes manually by using onSaveInstanceState and restore them in the onCreateMethod.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call

```
finish()
```

after the deletions operation of your activity